# Overtake a link when on Enter

Tags: javascript, events, enter

i know the title is weird but let me explain what i'm trying to do.
I have a login form with two input fields a checkbox and a submit button. Here is a screenshot:
[image]

The terms of use is a popup through which the user can see the terms of use. My problem is that when a user clicks the checkbox and presses the enter button the popup is appeared again. My desire is when the user clicks the checkbox and press the enter button to go to his homepage. How to do this? Is there a way to overtake opening the popup with on enter?

Comment: where is your code? so we can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `keydown` event in conjunction with the checkbox and test for the ENTER key press;

```js
document.querySelector("[type=checkbox]").addEventListener("keydown", function(evt){
   if(evt.keyCode === 13){
      console.log("you pressed ENTER");
      window.location = "http://cnn.com";
   }
});
```

```html
<input type=checkbox> Click me and then press ENTER
```

Keep in mind that client side code is not secure and this can be bypassed by a user. All security type code should happen on a server.

Comment: i'm using react.js and my input field is this: <input
        {...field.input}
        type="checkbox"
        className="form-control input-box__input"
        checked={field.value}
        onKeyDown={e => e.preventDefault()}
      /> Do you know how to adjust your code for my functionality

Comment: You didn't tag your question with React or provide your actual code (which you should always do when posting quesitons), but if you change the first line of my code from `querySelector("[type=checkbox]")` to `querySelector(".form-control[type=checkbox]")` and then remove the `onKeyDown` code completely, it should work.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Thanks a lot for the answer